# How to change layout in Bootstrap grid while see in mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

i m making website using bootstrap and new to design,

i m using two column of size 6 in row in bootstrap

```
|| Col-1 || Col-1 || [Web View]

|||||||||||
|| Col-1 ||
|||||||||||
|| Col-2 ||
||||||||||| [Mobile View]

But i want in mobile to be 

|||||||||||
|| Col-2 ||
|||||||||||
|| Col-1 ||
||||||||||| [Mobile View][What i wanted]
```

Reference : http://www.pluralsight.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pull + Pull](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to do something like this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

vanburenx is right just remember to code your HTML in the order you want it show on mobile. Then push/pull on larger layouts.